# Getting the sum of numbers in a csv column in Powershell and exporting to the same file

Tags: powershell, csv, sum

Lets say I'm trying to get the sum of values in a column in a CSV file.

I have a csv `fruits.csv`:

```
'Count','Food'
'4', 'apples'      
'2', 'pears'
'10', 'bananas'
'34', 'oranges'
'2', 'lemons'
```

I want to get the sum of the `Count` column and have it added to the bottom of the same csv file like this:

```
'Count','Food'
'4', 'apples'      
'2', 'pears'
'10', 'bananas'
'34', 'oranges'
'2', 'lemons'

Total: 52
```

This is my current code:

```
$file = `fruits.csv`
Get-Content $file | ConvertFrom-Csv | Measure-Object 'Count' -Sum | Export-Csv -append -force $file -NoTypeInformation
```

I tried to see if I could append the data that is similar to my desired output, but this wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It can certainly be done but it would no longer be a CSV:

```
$theCsv = Import-Csv path\to\source.csv

@(
    $theCsv | ConvertTo-Csv
    ''
    'Total: {0}' -f ($theCsv | Measure-Object Count -Sum).Sum
) | Set-Content path\to\thing.csv
```